# insufficient system storage.The server response was: Too many emails per connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I am sending two mails, one to admin address and another mail to a person who enters details saying "thanks for contacting us." in contact page.
In second mail/receipent mail, I get this error:

> "Insufficient system storage.The server response was: Too many emails per connection"

Second method `"SendConfirmationMail"` too gives same error.

> too many mails

```
private void SendMail()
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    System.IO.StreamReader r = null;
    r = new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/ContactMail.txt"));
    string body = r.ReadToEnd();
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("srinivas@gmail.com"));
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    //replacing txt file with dynamic content
    body = body.Replace("<%Name%>", Name);
    body = body.Replace("<%email%>", email);
    body = body.Replace("<%message%>", message);
    mail.Subject = "Applying For job";
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient MailServer = new SmtpClient();
    MailServer.Send(mail);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('Thank u for contacting us..');", true);
}
private void SendConfirmationMail()
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
    mail.Body = "Thank u for contacting us...";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Subject = "Thank you Mail";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient MailServer = new SmtpClient();
    MailServer.Send(mail);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('Thank u for contacting us..');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to a real smtp server:

```
     client = new SmtpClient() { Host = host, Port = port, Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password) };

    client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: im able to  send mail in first method , but not sending in second method @fernan

Comment: Only difference I can see is this: mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email)); vs mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("srinivas@gmail.com")); @Ananth Reddy